# Call puppet agent using java class

Tags: java, puppet

I have remote puppet master agents setup. I want to send requests to puppet agents using my java class. Is there any puppet API to call puppet agents using java class.?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as Puppet's API is RESTful, you can use any REST implementation you like.

As for the protocol specifics, see the [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/rest_api.html).

Answer (score 1):

In order to collect information when the agents have run the PuppetDB api might be useful too: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetdb/latest/api/.